# Fixed-length Sequences in Swift 2.2

Tags: generics, swift

The following is an implementation of fixed-length sequences that makes very exotic (and hopefully fun) use of Swift 2.2 types. The question is what exactly is the cost of having the type checker guaranteeing sequence length in this way on safety? performance? readability?

```
protocol CountType {
    static var count: Int { get }
}

protocol DigitType : CountType {}

enum _0 : DigitType { static let count = 0 }
enum _1 : DigitType { static let count = 1 }
enum _2 : DigitType { static let count = 2 }
enum _3 : DigitType { static let count = 3 }
enum _4 : DigitType { static let count = 4 }
enum _5 : DigitType { static let count = 5 }
enum _6 : DigitType { static let count = 6 }
enum _7 : DigitType { static let count = 7 }
enum _8 : DigitType { static let count = 8 }
enum _9 : DigitType { static let count = 9 }
```

At this point we can do very little:

```
_4.count // 4
_2.count // 2
```

To express larger natural numbers, however, we must combine `DigitTypes`:

```
import CoreGraphics // TODO: wean off (implement `pow`)

extension DigitType {
    static func value(place place: Int) -> Int {
        return count * Int(pow(10, CGFloat(place)))
    }
}

enum __<T:DigitType, U:DigitType> : CountType { // these are two underscores `_`x2 (then, below, three, four...)
    static var count: Int {
        return T.value(place: 1) + U.value(place: 0)
    }
}
enum ___<H:DigitType, T:DigitType, U:DigitType> : CountType {
    static var count: Int {
        return H.value(place: 2) + T.value(place: 1) + U.value(place: 0)
    }
}
enum ____<Th:DigitType, H:DigitType, T:DigitType, U:DigitType> : CountType {
    static var count: Int {
        return Th.value(place: 3) + H.value(place: 2) + T.value(place: 1) + U.value(place: 0)
    }
}
```

... which allows us to count in types (try it in the playground):

```
____<_2,_0,_1,_6>.count // 2016
```

The point is that we can now make use of `CountType`s to define sequence length:

```
final class Box<T> {
    var value: T
    init(_ value: T) { self.value = value }
}

struct Vector<Dimension: CountType, Element> : SequenceType {

    private let array: [Box<Element>]
    var elements: [Element] { return array.map{ $0.value } }

    subscript(index: Int) -> Box<Element> { return array[index] }

    init(_ repeatedValue: Element) {
        array = (0..<Dimension.count).map{ _ in Box(repeatedValue) }
    }

    func generate() -> Array<Element>.Generator {
        return elements.generate()
    }
}

// TODO: Matrix<Rows: CountType, Cols: CountType, Element>
```

We may now work with such `Vector`s and `Matrix`es with confidence that their dimension can never change:

```
let v = Vector<__<_4,_2>,Int>(0)
v.elements.count // 42

let w = Vector<_3,Int>(0)
w.elements // [0, 0, 0]
w[2].value = 5

for x in w {
    x // 0, 0, 5
}
```

(hm... the underscore syntax looks prettier in my playground...)

I was considering various alternative naming schemes for the combining enums. So, instead of underscores, we could perhaps emulate the exponent syntax for number literals (like `0.42e2` meaning `0.42 * pow(10, 2)`). This would work out as following:

```
e4<_2,_0,_1,_6>.count // 2016

// and

let v = Vector<e2<_4,_2>,Int>(0)
```

The reason I decided against this and similar approaches is that there is now a rather irrelevant number `2` appearing alongside `_4,_2`...

Comment: I have rolled back some of your edits. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Vogel612: That's fine, sorry about that. What do you think I should do if I had some subsequent thoughts and ideas on the matter (if anything)? Should I post an answer?

Comment: That seems to be a useful option here, yes

Answer (score 2):

The `Vector` type is not related to graphics, so importing
`CoreGraphics` seems "unnatural" here. If you replace `CGFloat`
by `Float` or `Double`

```
extension DigitType {
    static func value(place place: Int) -> Int {
        return count * Int(pow(10, Double(place)))
    }
}
```

then it suffices to import `Foundation` (or `Swift` + `Darwin`).

But I would get rid of the floating point conversion and implement it as (taking the hundreds as an example):

```
enum ___<H: DigitType, T: DigitType, U: DigitType> : CountType {
    static var count: Int {
        return H.count * 100 + T.count * 10  + U.count
    }
}
```

This is simple and straightforward, and easy to read. This makes the
`value(place place:)` with its floating point conversion, and the
the math library call to the `pow()` function obsolete.

As a consequence, the entire code compiles with a pure

```
import Swift
```

without additional imports.

---

*(This is my major point.)* The boxing of the array elements into
a `class` seems problematic to me.

First, `struct Vector` is a *value type*, but its elements are
mutable even for a constant:

```
let vecA = Vector<_3, Int>(0)
vecA[0].value = 111 // This should not compile!
```

Second, copying a vector copies *references* to the elements,
which is not to be expected for a value type:

```
let vecA = Vector<_3, Int>(0)
vecA[0].value = 111

let vecB = vecA
vecB[0].value = 222

print(vecA[0].value) // Output: 222. Expected output: 111.
```

Here, modifying the elements of `vecB` modifies the elements of
`vecA` as well.

I would simply omit the boxing and store the elements just as an
array. Modifying the elements is then done via a subscript setter:

```
struct Vector<Dimension: CountType, Element> {

    private var array: [Element]

    init(_ repeatedValue: Element) {
        array = [Element](count: Dimension.count, repeatedValue: repeatedValue)
    }

    var elements: [Element] {
        return array
    }

    subscript(index: Int) -> Element {
        get {
            return array[index]
        }
        set(newValue) {
            array[index] = newValue
        }
    }

    func generate() -> Array<Element>.Generator {
        return array.generate()
    }
}
```

Using a `private var array` for the element storage and a 
computed `elements` property still makes sense for encapsulation.

Now `Vector` behaves like a proper value type:

```
var vecA = Vector<_3, Int>(0)
vecA[0] = 111

var vecB = vecA
vecB[0] = 222

print(vecA[0]) // Output: 111
```

---

By adopting the `CustomStringConvertible` protocol,

```
extension Vector : CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        return "<" + (array.map { String($0) }).joinWithSeparator(", ") + ">"
    }
}
```

printing a vector produces nicer output (the angle brackets are just
an example to disambiguate the output from an array):

```
print(vecA)
// Output: <111, 0, 0>
// instead of Vector<_3, Int>(array: [111, 0, 0])
```

---

To create (constant) vectors, an `init` method taking a "index to
element mapping" might be useful:

```
extension Vector {
    init(elementForIndex: Int -> Element) {
        array = (0 ..< Dimension.count).map(elementForIndex)
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let vecC = Vector<_5, Int>(elementForIndex: { 2 * $0 })
print(vecC) // <0, 2, 4, 6, 8>
```

This would also come in handy when you start to define operations
on the vector type, e.g. an addition of integer vectors:

```
func + <Dimension, Element: IntegerArithmeticType>
    (lhs: Vector<Dimension, Element>, rhs: Vector<Dimension, Element>)
    -> Vector<Dimension, Element> {
        return Vector(elementForIndex: { lhs[$0] + rhs[$0]})
}
```

---

Initialization from an array or array literal might also be
convenient:

```
extension Vector {
    init(elements: [Element]) {
        precondition(elements.count == Dimension.count)
        array = elements
    }
}

extension Vector: ArrayLiteralConvertible {
    init(arrayLiteral elements: Element...) {
        self.init(elements: elements)
    }
}
```

Example:

```
let vecD: Vector<_5, Double> = [ 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0 ]
print(vecD) // <1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0>
```

The disadvantage here is that the compiler cannot check the
dimension.

Comment: Thank you Martin for such a careful response. If you don't mind I've added a section to my post to reflect on your ideas. +1 and a big thanks!

Comment: @milos: You are welcome. – I am not sure if I understand what you meant with `private(set) public var array`, that is not what I suggested. – In my opinion, the disadvantage that array elements are references (in your implementation) is larger that than the disadvantage that *internal* methods might modify the vector size (in my suggested implementation). The first can cause problems due to wrong usage of your type, the second would be a programming error.  But that is just my opinion!

Comment: Martin (how do I tag you, given that there is a space?), I was referring to your line `private var array: [Element]`, which in that case might as well be accessible as `public private(set) var`... I like your distinction between the boxed in and private access values. All I'm saying is that I have no inclination to argue either way. This post was not about that. Though I am beginning to regret it, I only chose to box in the values to emphasise the "fixed-length" use case of the main idea, which is to count in types. Either way, it's always a pleasure discussing code with you.

Comment: `Foundation` is a huge import compared to `CoreGraphics`. `Darwin` would work though... Of course, as I pointed out from the start, I should need neither.